# Does Rails make a new connection to memcached server for every cached fragment in the view or does it retrieve everything in one connection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, memcached, dalli

I'm using dalli gem as a memcached client in my Rails 4 app. Having multiple cached fragments in my view I couldn't but wonder how efficiently does Rails handles retrieval of data from memcached server. Does it make a new connection per each fragment or does it retrieve all the necessary fragments in a single connection?